# What do "capsize", "wobble", and "weave" mean when referring to bike stability?

Tags: geometry, handling

Some research into (uncontrolled) bicycle stability (e.g. [Jason K. Moore, Human Control of a Bicycle, 2012](https://moorepants.github.io/dissertation/parameterstudy.html#geometric-variation)) models the dynamic behavior of some bikes and determines "critical speeds" for "capsize" and "weave" modes (another source mentions "wobble").

What is the definition of these terms?

Answer (score 2):

https://moorepants.github.io/dissertation/eom.html?highlight=weave#linearized-equations-of-motion

> Capsize is always real and stable at low speeds but becomes marginally unstable at a higher speed. It describes the roll of the rear frame. Weave is real at very low speeds and describes an inverted pendulum-like motion i.e. the bicycle falls over. As speed increases the eigenvalues coalesce into a complex conjugate pair at the weave bifurcation that describes an exponentially increasing sinusoidal motion of roll and steer, with steer lagging the roll. This mode becomes stable at a higher speed. The weave and capsize critical speeds bound the stable speed range.

Also

https://www.dynamotion.it/dinamoto/8_on-line_papers/wobble-weave/wobble-weave_eng.html

> The wobble mode is essentially a steering oscillation of the front forks; this mode doesn't involve the rear frame in any significant way.

> The weave mode is a side-to-side motion of the entire motorcycle characterised by a coupling of the yaw and roll oscillations with a significant lateral displacement of the steering axis.

> Capsize
> ...
> this motion is a non-oscillatory motion and consists in the capsize of the two-wheel vehicle.

---

Explanations and lots of references in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics

> Since 1971, when he identified and named the wobble, weave and capsize modes,[12] Robin Sharp has written regularly about the behavior of motorcycles and bicycles.[13]

and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_and_motorcycle_dynamics#Modes

- Capsize is the word used to describe a bike falling over without oscillation.
- Weave is the word used to describe a slow (0–4 Hz) oscillation between leaning left and steering right, and vice versa
- Wobble, shimmy, tank-slapper, speed wobble, and death wobble are all words and phrases used to describe a rapid (4–10 Hz) oscillation of primarily just the front end (front wheel, fork, and handlebars).

Answer (score 2):

The animated illustrations in ["Vibration modes of motorcycles"
by Vittore Cossalter, Roberto Lot](http://web.archive.org/save/http://www.dynamotion.it/dinamoto/8_on-line_papers/wobble-weave/wobble-weave_eng.html) (posted in the community wiki answer) do a great job of illustrating capsize, weave, and wobble.

Simplified verbal approximations might be:

**Capsize - The bicycle moves as if to fall over on its side with no distinct oscillations**.

**Weave - The bicycle moves with an oscillating pattern as if arcing between cones on a straight path without inducing movement at the handlebars** (perhaps subtly more complex because of the perpendicular twisting motions of yaw and roll axes of the entire bicycle object).

**Wobble - The bicycle moves distinctly at the front due to twisting movements of the handlebar to turn the front wheel back and forth** (isolating twisting motion largely at the fork steering tube axis). *To further contrast with weave, the front wheel might arc back and forth between cones on a straight path while the handlebar flops side-to-side but the rear wheel remains largely in place striking each cone.*

Answer (score 1):

When at speed, a bicycle's uncontrolled motion is dominated by three fundamental motion types (caster, capsize, and weave). The actual motion of the bicycle will typically be a sum of these motion types, but you can also cause the bicycle to exhibit each of these motion types distinctly.

Caster is the rapid always stable non-oscillatory motion of the fork/handlebar to center under the frame when traveling forward (when traveling backward it is unstable!). This is the same primary behavior you observe on the caster wheel of an office chair.

Capsize is the non-oscillatory motion of the bike to right itself back to equilibrium (low speeds) or slowly spiral into the ground (high speeds). There is a small steer angle coupled with an ever decreasing or increasing roll angle.

Weave is the oscillatory coupled motion of fork/handlebar steer and the rear frame roll that is stable at high speeds but unstable at low speeds. This can be observed by pushing your bicycle up to speed (without a rider) and laterally perturbing the bicycle frame. It will oscillate and stabilize.

The critical speeds are the speeds at which the weave motion stabilizes and the capsize motion destabilizes. These bound a self-stable speed range, which most bicycle designs have. This plot is the now classic way to show the critical speeds:

[image]

v is the forward speed of the bicycle. The solid lines represent the real parts of the eigenvalues of a dynamic model of a bicycle linearized about the upright zero steer constant speed configuration. A dynamic system is stable when all of the real parts of the eigenvalues are negative and unstable if any of the real parts are positive. The speeds at which the solid lines cross the abscissa indicate when a motion type changes from stable to unstable or vice versa.